# aws mariadb set file_priv to Y

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb

Is it possible to set file_priv to Y in MariaDB on AWS? I see that rdsadmin has file_priv=Y. My 'admin' user has file_priv=N and if I try to set it to Y, I get an error.

To avoid all the "Why in Hell would you ever want to do that!?!?!?" questions... Every month, I receive a set of CSV files totaling around 200GB. I need to push those into the database to parse them, move pertinent data into the reporting tables, and then delete the data. I *could* upload the CSV files one query at a time. It takes a very long to do that. I could do an insert with multiple rows. I hit the row limit and have to do multiple queries - which takes a long time. I could parse all the data locally, but I don't want to. I want to do it in the database, not with a bunch of awk and sed commands. The hangup appears to be that file_priv=N, so I can't upload a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File` privilege is only required with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, which loads data from a file on the server's filesystem.

You can't access the server's filesystem with RDS so there is no need for that privilege.

Using the `mysql` cli, or any other client that supports it, you should be able to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from a file on your local filesystem, and this shouldn't require the `File` privilege.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that my work having been on one server made such a big difference with a little keyword. I didn't have to use "local" before. I see that I do now. I wish the error message wasn't "You aren't allowed" but "You can do it locally" instead.

Comment: Doing it locally involves a more convoluted interaction between client and server, and not all clients support it.  Note also that the [`mysqlimport` command line utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) is essentially a wrapper for `LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE`, potentially cleaner for use with automation than the `mysql` cli, since it writes (and escapes) the query for you.  Add `--local` for a local file. (For some reason, I was thinking this was deprecated, but apparently it isn't.)